# SQL Error Code 1066 Unique Alias

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

Having this issue where it's giving me an error code for not unique table/alias. Code is as follows:

```
SELECT
  eventplanline.PlanNo,
  LineNo,
  ResNo,
  NumberFld,
  LocName,
  TimeStart,
  TimeEnd
FROM Facility, Location, Resourcetbl,
  Eventplan u1
  INNER JOIN eventplanline u2 ON u1.PlanNO = u2.PlanNo
  ,
  Eventplanline
  INNER JOIN Resourcetbl u3 ON u2.ResNO = u3.ResNo
  ,
  eventplanline
  INNER JOIN eventrequest u4 ON u2.eventNo = u4.EventNo
WHERE Activity = 'Operation'
      AND WorkDate BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2013-12-31'
      AND FacName = 'Basketball Arena';
```

I've added the u2, u3, u4 because it was a solution in a nother similar problem. However It still doesnt fix the issue.

Comment: Don't use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Can you provide the columns in the tables Facility and EventPlan?

Comment: Facility - FacNo, FacName,| Eventplan - PlanNo, EventNo, Workdate,. Notes, Activity, EmpNo

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific on your alias naming convention. Once you give a table an alias, stick to using that alias.  I see in your code you may give a table an alias; use the alias once for the two part naming convention, then use the table name for a different two part naming convention.  Be more consistent.  Also try going to a two part naming convention in your select statement.  [alias].[column_name]

Comment: I tried being more consistent(not sure if I am), but it still ends up giving me the same error saying "error code 1066: eventplanline not unique..". I'll update my code to what I am doing now.